# How to stop a running SparkContext before opening the new one

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am executing tests in Scala with Spark creating a SparkContext as follows:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("test")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

After the first execution there was no error. But now I am getting this message (and a failed test notification):

```
Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243).
```

It looks like I need to check if there is any running SparkContext and stop it before launching a new one (I do not want to allow multiple contexts).
How can I do this?

UPDATE:

I tried this, but there is the same error (I am running tests from IntellijIdea and I make the code before executing it):

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("test")
                          // also tried: .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
```

UPDATE 2:

```
class TestApp extends SparkFunSuite with TestSuiteBase {

  // use longer wait time to ensure job completion
  override def maxWaitTimeMillis: Int = 20000

  System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port")
  System.clearProperty("spark.hostPort")

  var ssc: StreamingContext = _
  val config: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("test")
                                         .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
  val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(config)

//...

test("Test1")
{

sc.stop()
}

}
```

Comment: This is a common error. Depending on your test framework, you should use `before`/`after` blocks in your tests to share the same spark context throughout your tests and stop your context only when all your tests finished

Comment: @jarandaf: could you please point to some example of using `before / after ` in this context?

Comment: You might want to check this out (https://spark-summit.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Testing-Spark-Best-Practices-Anupama-Shetty-Neil-Marshall.pdf) although it is a little bit "old" to get you started

Comment: Try keeping the sc.stop() statement in the main function itself where the sparkcontext is defined and check whether it resolves the error

Answer (score 25):

**To stop existing context** you can use [`stop`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1692) method on a given `SparkContext` instance.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

val conf: SparkConf = ???
val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
...
sc.stop()
```

**To reuse existing context or create a new one** you can use [`SparkContex.getOrCreate`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2276) method.

```
val sc1 = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
...
val sc2 = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
```

When used in test suites both methods can be used to achieve different things:

- `stop` - stopping context in `afterAll` method (see for example [`MLlibTestSparkContext.afterAll`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/86ca8fefc8a147b31952b8a00e58e46d93bb8bc4/mllib/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLlibTestSparkContext.scala#L47))
- `getOrCreate` - to get active instance in individual test cases (see for example [`QuantileDiscretizerSuite`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/89a41c5b7a3f727b44a7f615a1352ca006d12f73/mllib/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/QuantileDiscretizerSuite.scala#L30))